# Attachment vk jodejs

Tags: node.js, вконтакте

Как в вк юзать attachment в методе message.send?

При попытке написать message.send.attachment[photo-3563466_246744] не работает.

Юзаю старую версию vk-io (для страницы вк).
Пытался примеры искать их пробовал но итога 0

Answer (score 0):

```
message.send(`ваш текст`, { attachment: 'photo-3563466_246744' });
```